# get elements by class which is contained in form with id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of forms on the page and need to differentiate them for validation. I have a form id and all fields which need to be validated have validate class, I need to select all elements from specific form with class validate, I tried

```
$("#service_partners.validate")
```

but the result is an empty array

Comment: You forgot the space: `$("#service_partners .validate")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#service_partners.validate` selects elements that have the class `validate` and the id `service_partners`.  The selector you're looking for is `#service_partners .validate`.

The space says "All the elements with the class `validate` that are contained within the element with the id of `service_partners`."

For more explanation on how selectors like these work, check out [the MDN article on CSS-style selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)